# Copy one excel file contents to the end of the other excel file

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

How do i copy one excel file to another excel file using VBA How do i mention the paths of the two excel files?

This is what i found on the internet:

```
ActiveSheet.Move After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
```

This is what i saw but im unable to make it can anyone tell me the way i can make it?

I have to copy all the rows and columns of one excel file to the end of the other excel file.
 How do I make it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to move (or copy) worksheets from a workbook to another, you have to **set the other workbook in a var**. Let me give you an example:

```
Dim oNewWB as Workbook
Dim oCurWB as Workbook
'Store active workbook in a var
Set oCurWB = ActiveWorkbook
'Open a new workbook
Set oNewWB = Application.Workbooks.Open(<pathToWorkbookHere>)

'Move "Sheet1" from the current workbook to new one
oCurWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Move After:=oNewWB.Sheets(oNewWB.Sheets.Count)
```

[EDIT] New piece of code as suggested by Maverik
Let's say you want to copy **every** sheet in your workbook to the new one:

```
Dim oNewWB as Workbook
Dim oCurWB as Workbook
Dim Sheet as Worksheet
'Store active workbook in a var
Set oCurWB = ActiveWorkbook
'Open a new workbook
Set oNewWB = Application.Workbooks.Open(<pathToWorkbookHere>)

For Each Sheet In oCurWB.Sheets
  'Move "Sheet1" from the current workbook to new one
  Sheet.Move After:=oNewWB.Sheets(oNewWB.Sheets.Count)
Next Sheet
```

HTH

Comment: I think OP wants to write every sheet in one file to other and perhaps adding a `For Each` bit to your code will make it perfect (perhaps as a separate bit, so as to have both cases covered)

Comment: Pleasure! +1 for the perfect solution that other stumblers can use regardless of which mode they're looking for